# Easy Localization] [WARNING] Localization key not found<…>

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am trying to add Easy Localization package to my Flutter app. I have followed all steps, one by one, by i don't know why i get the error:
Easy Localization] [WARNING] Localization key not found<…>

I run the code in `main.dart`, and i have 3 buttons to choose a language in my `LanguageScreen.dart`

**this is my main.dart:**

```
Future <void> function() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

runApp(
  EasyLocalization(
   supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('it', 'IT'), Locale('fr', 'FR')],
   path: 'assets/translations', // <-- change the path of the translation files
   fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
   assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
   child: MyLangApp(),
   ),
  );
 }
```

**this is MyLangApp:**

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'LanguagesScreen.dart';


class MyLangApp extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyLangApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<MyLangApp> createState() => _MyLangAppState();
  }

class _MyLangAppState extends State<MyLangApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
    supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
    locale: context.locale,
    home: LanguagesScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my LanguageScrenn.dart**

```
child: CupertinoFormSection.insetGrouped(
        header:  Text('choose_a_language'.tr().toString()),
          children: [

            TextButton(onPressed: () async {
              await context.setLocale(Locale('en','US'));
              print(context.supportedLocales);
            },
                child: Text('English', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),))),
            TextButton(onPressed: () async {
              await context.setLocale(Locale('fr','FR'));
            },
                child: Text('French', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),)),
            TextButton(onPressed: () async {
              await context.setLocale(Locale('it','IT'));
            },
                child: Text('Italian', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),)),
          ]
```

**This is my language file:**

```
{
"calculator": "Calculateur",
"flour": "Farine",
"settings": "Reglages",
"change_language": "Changer de Langue",
"choose_a_language": "Choisir une Langue",
"flour_achieve": "Flour Strenght to achieve",
"enter_W": "Entrez (W)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some steps...
first you need to create an assets folder with name translations and create your target translation languages with .json extension like the example below

```
assets
└── translations
    ├── fr-FR.json
    └── en-US.json
    └── it-IT.json
```

Declare your assets localization directory in pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/translations/
```

every json file must contain fixed key and value contain translated words :

for example en-US.json :

```
{
"calculator": "Calculator",
"flour": "Flour",
"settings": "Settings",
"change_language": "Change language",
"choose_a_language": "Choose a language",
"flour_achieve": "Flour Strength to achieve",
"enter_W": "Enter (W)"
}
```

and fr-FR.json :

```
{
"calculator": "Calculatrice",
"flour": "Farine",
"settings": "Reglages",
"change_language": "Changer de Langue",
"choose_a_language": "Choisir une Langue",
"flour_achieve": "Farine Force à atteindre",
"enter_W": "Entrez (W)"
}
```

and finally your text widget will look like this:

```
header:  Text('choose_a_language').tr(),
```